# Getting mysql row version number?

Tags: mysql, sql, versioning, database-versioning

I have a database where everything is versioned inside itself using `start_date` and `end_date`

What I want to do is dynamically get a version number for a row.

So, get all rows with a particular item_id ordered by start_date and then given a `start_date` and `end_date` that will isolate it down to one row. what I want is to find out where that row sits.

e.g. the data

```
id | item_id | start_date
1  | 1       | 01-31-2012
2  | 1       | 02-31-2012
3  | 2       | 02-31-2012
4  | 1       | 03-31-2012
5  | 2       | 05-31-2012
6  | 1       | 04-31-2012
```

if using `select id from items where item_id = 2 and start_date = 05-31-2012`

would return `5` so what I would want for the version would be `2`

if using `select id from items where item_id = 1 and start_date = 03-31-2012`

would return `4` so what I would want for the version would be `3`

The only way I can think of to do this would be to select all rows with the item_id of whatever, and then loop over each item checking the start_date, if it is not what I want increase version_number by 1.

Is there a way to do it with just mysql?

Comment: How do you define the version as 2 and 3 in the above example. Please explain in detail.

Comment: @NilamDoctor because the matching rows with the selected dates are the 2nd and 3rd rows with that item_id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) version
FROM items
WHERE item_id = 2 AND start_date <= '2012-05-31'
```

or `id <= 5` instead of date comparison (assuming `id` is unique and grows monotonously)

Comment: this wouldn't work for the add new version such as SELECT COUNT(*) version FROM test7 WHERE item_id = 1 AND start_date <= '2012-05-30';

Comment: @Drew Pierce: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The query does exactly what OP explained in the question.

Comment: except when he said , if it is not what I want increase version_number by 1.

Comment: @Drew Pierce: I'm sure it's alright. If you think it's wrong - ask the OP on the question comments to clarify this case for you.

Answer (score 0):

this one works in oracle..use analytic function row_number() in inner select query as below

```
select version from (select row_number() over ( partition by item_id  order by start_date ) version,item.* from item) where start_date ='05-31-2012'
```